# Slide up animation on up scroll based on div position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a smoother transition by making the background for .header slide up rather than just disappear when the bottom of div "1" hits the top of the page and the .header background changes from white to transparent. I've tried to achieve this by adding class .BGupTranisition to the CSS and jQuery (//up scroll - else{) but this doesn't work? Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?? :-)

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var header = $('.header');
    var stage0 = $('.stage-0');
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
        // down scroll
        if (scrollTop > stage0.offset().top + stage0.height()) {
            header.addClass('hide');
        }
    } else {
        // up scroll
        if (scrollTop <= stage0.offset().top + stage0.height()) {
            header.removeClass('headerBGchange headerLIchange');
        } else {
            header.removeClass('hide').addClass('headerBGchange headerLIchange BGupTranistion');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
.header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s ease;
    transition: top .5s ease;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header ul {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.header ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.hide {
    top: -80px;
}

.headerBGchange {
    Background: white;
}

.BGupTranistion {
   <!--slide back up animation-->
}

.header.headerLIchange ul li {
    color: Blue;
}
.stage {
    color: #fff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: bisque;
    font-size: 48px;
 
}
.stage-0 {
    background: black;
}

.stage-1 {
    background: #030202;
}

.stage-2 {
    background: #060505;
}

.stage-3 {
    background: #080707;
}

.stage-4 {
    background: #0b0a09;
}

.stage-5 {
    background: #0e0c0b;
}

.stage-6 {
    background: #110e0e;
}

.stage-7 {
    background: #141110;
}

.stage-8 {
    background: #161312;
}

.stage-9 {
    background: #191515;
}

.stage-10 {
    background: #1c1817;
}

.stage-11 {
    background: #1f1a19;
}

.stage-12 {
    background: #221d1c;
}

.stage-13 {
    background: #241f1e;
}

.stage-14 {
    background: #272120;
}

.stage-15 {
    background: #2a2422;
}

.stage-16 {
    background: #2d2625;
}

.stage-17 {
    background: #302827;
}

.stage-18 {
    background: #322b29;
}

.stage-19 {
    background: #352d2c;
}

.stage-20 {
    background: #38302e;
}

.stage-21 {
    background: #3b3230;
}

.stage-22 {
    background: #3e3432;
}

.stage-23 {
    background: #413735;
}

.stage-24 {
    background: #433937;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="stage stage-0">1</div>
<div class="stage stage-2">3</div>
<div class="stage stage-4">5</div>
<div class="stage stage-6">7</div>
<div class="stage stage-8">9</div>
<div class="stage stage-10">11</div>
<div class="stage stage-12">13</div>
<div class="stage stage-14">15</div>
<div class="stage stage-16">17</div>
<div class="stage stage-18">19</div>
<div class="stage stage-20">21</div>
<div class="stage stage-22">23</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that background is a property of `div` that occupies the same area as the div itself. Having said that, you can't move out the `div`'s background without moving the content of the div without playing around with the text property.

The solution to this is if you play around with vertical `linear-gradient` color in the `.header { background: /* linear-gradient value here */ }` or you can create another `div` with white background behind the `div.header` that slide up when you wanted to and make the `div.header` bacground transparent.

The first method would require you to calculate the value based on the scrolling value in your javascript.